# C#: SQL Getting the Last row from a SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, .net

I needed to sort the dates in a table column and get the last row (i.e.: the latest date) from the reader.  I tried the following:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From ActivityTable 
                                             ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, Date) ASC", con);
   con.Open();
   SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   //I need to skip reading all the rows UNTIL the last row. I only need the last row
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
     locationOfPrevious = rdr["Location"].ToString();
     nodeid_previous = rdr["NodeID"].ToString();

   }
   rdr.Close();
}
```

I believe the query is right but I can't get the LAST row from the query results (that is the last date recorded according to the sort). What do yall suggest? Thanks folks :)

Comment: [Sql Basics Tutorial - Order By](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-clause.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'd suggest ordering by desc and taking the first row - more efficient

Comment: Why didn't I think of that Lmao xD That was the best. Thanks man :P

Comment: I get a 'IndexOutOfRange Exception" though

Comment: check the fields "Location" and "NodeID" exist and are correctly spelled?

Comment: @MWUser edit what you changed your code to above so we can see why you would be getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
Select Top 1 * From ActivityTable ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, Date) DESC //SQL
```

you can use `LIMIT` keyword to generate the same output in `MySQL`

```
Select * From ActivityTable ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, Date) DESC LIMIT 0,1 //MYSQL
```

Comment: `TOP` is not valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: in MySql that would be equiv to the key word `LIMIT`